# How python instantiates integer from numeric literals

Tags: python

My question is very simple and short and maybe stupid: what happens between the moment when interpreter handles a line like this:

```
x = 1
```

and when this `x` is assigned and integer object? Which machinery helps interpreter to know which object to instantiate?

I have a very little knowledge about python lexical analysis, but I understand that there is some machinery that splits code line into tokens and there are some rules described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals). But I can't find out how does interpreter transforms literal `1` to the instance of integer object.

Does interpreter says something like "*Ok, here we have a numeric literal, so now we should go the some mapping of literals to objects and find out which kind of object we should instantiate now?*" If so, where I can get more internals about this process? It's just curiosity, but I can't find something related in python docs or Google.

Comment: Interesting question. While looking into it, I found this page: [Python integer objects implementation](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/), which may be of interest to you.

Comment: @Kevin thank you. I saw this article, it's interesting.